# breakpoint function executed x times

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I want to use a breakpoint when a certain code (function) is executed for a certain number of times. The problem is that my easy code is optimalized out and the breakpoint is never reached. How can i break a code after it excecuted a certain number of times

```
static int count = 0;
static int test = 0;
if (count == 5) {
    //Break here before getting stuck
    count++;
    test++;
    count--;
};
```

Comment: Try declaring `count` `volatile`.

Comment: You can remove any optimisations. You can do that in the `c++` settings of your project. But there shall be no optimisation if you build you project in `DEBUG` mode!?! You can give an BP some additional properties.. e.g. a number of hits before break.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/od-disable-debug?view=msvc-140

Comment: why you don't put the breakpoint before if?

Answer (score 0):

You answered on your question: Breakpoint is never reached. And your code never execured requested number of times.

So, you can disable optimization.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Since it is a large code is it also possible to do that for only that part of the funtion. I tried #pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize("O0") ending with #pragma GCC pop_options but that introduced errors.

Comment: @Meng Visual Studio uses MSVC, not GCC. By changing to debug configuration, the code should not get optimised (Project > Properties > Config:Debug)

Answer (score 0):

Always when compiling for debugging, switch off ( or keep it at minimal ) all the optimisations ( -O0 ).

Alternatively when using gcc, you can use function attributes to tell compiler to not optimise a function ( using **attribute**((optimize(0))) )

Answer (score 0):

you can try `__debugbreak();` function when your condition is fulfilled.